# RestKit Response map issue - <RKMappingResult:, results={ "<null>" =

Tags: ios6, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using rest kit 0.20.0. I have a request in JSON format which is like

```
{
  "CreateSession" : yes,
  "DistributionChannel" : "string1",
  "Login" : "string2",
  "Nickname" :"string3",
  "Password" :"string4",
  "PhysicalDevice" :
   {
     "DeviceId" : "string5",
     "DeviceTypeCode" : 123,
     "PhysicalDeviceTypeCode" : 1233,
    }
}
```

I did this

```
 NSDictionary * dictionary = @{
                            @"CreateSession":@"yes",
                            @"DistributionChannel":@"string1",
                            @"Login": @"string2",
                            @"Nickname":  @"string3",
                            @"Password":  @"string4",
                            @"PhysicalDevice":  @{ @"DeviceId":  @"string5",
                                                   @"DeviceTypeCode":  @"123",
                                                   @"PhysicalDeviceTypeCode": @"1233" }
                            };


    RKObjectMapping *registerDeviceRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
        [registerDeviceRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:dictionary];
```

created descriptors for request and response separately. Added it to the RKObjectManager shared object,also have set base url and headers.

I called this to start request

```
RKHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:dictionary method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"RegisterDevice" parameters:nil];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"response   %@",[responseObject description]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

        [operation start];
```

I get a 200 status but could not map values from response. The mapping result that I got is

```
<RKMappingResult: 0x849bf60, results={
    "<null>" = "<Response: 0x849b390>";
```

Tried several links but seems like none provides a good solution. The actual response that i need to map is

```
{
    "PhysicalDevice": {
        "AddDate": "string1",
        "AuthenticationKey": "string2",
        "DeviceId": "string3",
        "DeviceTypeCode": 33,
        "DeviceTypeName": "string4",
        "Id": 10130,
        "ModDate": "2013-09-27T07:21:34.240Z",
        "PhysicalDeviceTypeCode": 1233,
        "SerialNumber": "string5",
        "Status": 1,
        "StatusName": "string6"
    },
    "RemainingDeviceAssociations": 4,
    "SessionId": "string7"
}
```

Note: values in request and response are dummy values, but their structure is as given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<RKMappingResult: 0x849bf60, results={
>       "<null>" = "<Response: 0x849b390>";`

This looks like a valid response. The response mapping provides you with a dictionary where the key is the key path and the response is your designated object. So, in this case the key is `nil` and your object is `Response`. And `Response` doesn't implement the `description` method so you just get the address.

You haven't shown your mappings or descriptors so I can't say more. You may be able to look at the contents of `Response` in the debugger...